# What is the difference between system memory and internal storage?

Tags: internal-storage, storage

I am using LG Optimus L3.

When I look into the app manager, there is a system memory of 157MB and an internal storage of 1GB. I can't install all the apps on internal storage. It's something like internal SD card.

Can I somehow extend the system memory and shrink internal storage?

Comment: You can't simply change the sizes. Butt you could use App2SD to move apps from "phone storage" to the card.

Comment: Are you suggesting that by "extending the system memory" you could install apps on it?!

Comment: @Izzy: that could easily break the app, though.  Most modern versions of Android (Froyo on up) automatically install on SD card unless the app *has* to be installed in system memory.

Comment: @Logos if the *native* App2SD offers to move the app, it should not break the app -- unless the dev made errors compiling his Manifest to state it should not be moved. If you *force* incompatible apps to be moved, that's a different case -- but I was of course not suggesting *that*.

Comment: Ah. There is an app called App2SD, which is what I assume you were referring to.  I don't think I've ever seen anyone use that term for Android's built in app manager's feature before.

Answer (score 2):

"System Storage" is where the OS and the System Applications are installed. This could also be considered where the User application are installed (based on your question). User installed applications are installed in /data/apps, settings and app data is stored in /data/data, and then application cache data is stored in /cache. These are all part of the "System Storage".

Internal Storage is an area that is used like an sdcard. As far as the Android OS is concerned, it is an sdcard. Some applications may save data to it, but it is mainly used as direct storage for your stuff. Like pictures taken with the camera, music, ringtones, things like that.

You cannot just adjust the size of system memory. Is it technically possible, yes. But doing so could require you to have knowledge of linux tool, rooting, custom roms, recoveries, and even possibly having to compile your own linux kernel and ROM or other information that I am not thinking of at the moment. Which is well beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Ryan is correct - I've done something similar on my old G1 to increase system memory enough to install Froyo, and it is not a simple task even for an experienced user.

Comment: @Logos, I agree. But still some kernel developers are now implementing pain free ways of adjusting system partition thru recovery or simple kernel flash. [XDA forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) has plenty of guides on how to do this.

Comment: @forums: the problem with XDA forum guides is that they are often geared at a higher level than the average noob, and assume background knowledge that might not be present.  I'm no noob, and I've found them confusing myself.  Plus there's often multiple guides posted, with different methods, and no way to discern which is the best/correct method between them for a more naive user.

Comment: Fair enough. It really depends on ones technical understanding for it to work. But what I'm pointing out is that, compared to the earlier generation, today's guides are more noob friendly :P