# Problem with internal memory of a S4 mini

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have 1 month old S4 mini with 32 gb of internal storage. . I have only installed 3 apps on it and now it tells me it has insufficient internal memory to install any more. I have 20 photos on it and no contacts. When I go to the storage section of the settings it tells me I have 32.00 of total space and 31.87 gb of available space. It says there is only 185 mb of apps and 13.63 kb of cached data. How can I correct this problem and download more apps? I do not have an sd card installed.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. This question seems to be a  duplicate of [What is the difference between system memory and internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38722/what-is-the-difference-between-system-memory-and-internal-storage). Check that question and answers and see if it helps solve your problem.

Comment: No, my problem seems to be different. The phone is virtually new, there is no sd card installed and only 3 apps are installed. By accessing settings/more/storage it tells me there is 31.87 gb of free space. Is this not the system memory?

Comment: No, all 31.87gb is not system memory. Most of that is internal storage. In short, Internal storage is like an SD card built in to the phone. (long answer in the question/answer I linked). You may have installed only 3 apps, but there are many other apps installed by the manufacturer/OS. Where apps are installed in part of "system storage", not internal storage. Think of system storage as where the OS and apps go, internal storage is where your pictures and music go.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is unfortunate then that I'll never be able to install more than a few apps onto my phone.

Comment: Brandon, you might wish to check with out [insufficient-menory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which contains some first-aid and links to more. A "remote diagnostic" is a little hard; if you had a terminal app, I'd ask you to post the output of `df`. Maybe you could [edit] your question and include at least a screenshot of *Settings › Storage* plus names+links of those 3 apps? Also, what Android version is running on your S4?

Answer (score 1):

Brandon...to find answer for your problem first you need to be sure does you have insufficient space because of full cache or because problem of specific app. If you have problems with every app, then you have cache problem probably. But before try to fix it, first try to download larger app from app you cant to install. if you can do it, then you dont have a problem with a cache.
I dont know you knowledge about working with android, but if you have fair knowledge, you should dont have a problem to fix it.
I dont search for solution for devices without root access, so I will write solutions for rooted devices only
You need:
- rooted device (google it how you can root your device, if it not rooted already)
- root checker (simple app to check if your device rooted correctly)
- super user app
- android terminal emulator
- es file explorer or root explorer (root explorer is not free, but it is very good app)

To fix cache problem, follow these steps:

1. You gonna need Android Terminal Simulator or equivalent terminal app. This will also require your Android rooted.
2. Type ’su’ (root permission request will be showned, you need to approve it).
3. Type ‘cd /’
4. Type ‘umount /cache’
5. Type ‘mount -o rw,remount -t rootfs rootfs /’ (to set the folder access to rw – read write)
6. Type ‘rmdir /cache’ (delete cache folder)
7. I personally using root explorer to do point 5-6
8. Type ‘mkdir /sdcard/cache’
9. Type ‘ln -s /sdcard/cache /cache’ (to link cache folder to /sdcard/cache – which shoud have bigger partition size)

(tutorial right goes to jimmy)

if you dont have cache problem, then check for any leftovers of that app at sdcard/android/data

for example I have "insufficient storage space" error when I try to install Shadow Fight 2 (about 90 mb), but I installed Soulcraft (about 200 mb) normally. I found .odex file of Shadow Fight 2 in data folder, and after I delete it, I was able to install Shadow Fight 2 again

However that mean does you already had installed that app before problem. As you said that your device is new and that you installed only 3 apps, then you probably have cache problem

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your internal memory is getting filled up with crash dumps.  These are saved in `/data/log` directory that isn't normally accessible.

If your phone is rooted, try clearing out the contents of this directory manually via Terminal Emulator or ADB.  The commands would be as follows:

```
adb shell
su
rm /data/log/*
```

If the phone is not rooted - try launching the **SysDump** utility by opening the Dialer app, dialing `#9900#`, and pressing Send.  This *should* open up the utility as seen in this [screenshot](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Screenshot_2013-11-01-14-49-54.png) and allow you to clean up the above folder by tapping the "Delete dumpstate/logcat" button.