# Why is my storage not using all of its storage?

Tags: storage

My phone says it has 8GB of memory but its only allowing me to use 4GB, why is this? I have already searched this in google but nothing has come up.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between system memory and internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38722/16575) / **[4Gb Storage: Why can it only use 1.6GB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/130273/16575)** / [Android Folder Hierarchy](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575). Please follow these links for details.

Answer (score 0):

A part of storage is used for the operating system (Android). In your case it's about 4 Gb.